# POST routes are not listing from root path Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5, routes

Using **Laravel 5.2**, there are **two forms** in a blade and they have to submit(POST) to two actions **from the root(`/`)**.

> Here is **app/Http/routes.php**

```
..    
Route::auth();

// Mails
Route::get('/contact', ['uses' => 'PageController@getContact', 'as' => 'contact']);
Route::post('/contact', ['uses' => 'PageController@postContact', 'as' => 'pages.postContact']);
Route::post('/', ['uses' => 'PageController@postGuestRegistration', 'as' => 'pages.postGuestRegistration']);
Route::post('/', ['uses' => 'PageController@postOnlineEnquiry', 'as' => 'pages.postOnlineEnquiry']);
...
```

> **`/contact` and other `get`, `post` and `resource` routes are running good.**

Consider only two POST routes from and to the root(`/`), here routes are listing but only for the last one in the list.

ie., **`pages.postOnlineEnquiry`** only.

Otherwise **`pages.postGuestRegistration`** only when I sort the list and take **`pages.postGuestRegistration`** after **`pages.postOnlineEnquiry`**.

I have a route group:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'pages'], function () {
   ...
   ...
   // only GET|HEAD routes come under /pages are listed here 
   ...
   ...
});
```

Is there a solutions for this?

I don't see any possible way even if I group these POST routes from the root path.

Now I **find no way to POST two forms to the same path and different actions.**

The Error shows:

> **Route [pages.postGuestRegistration] not defined.**

OR

> **Route [pages.postOnlineEnquiry] not defined.**

Comment: share your form also ?

Comment: You can't have two routes with the same path and method, there is no way that the server knows which one to use.  Consider either changing the path or the method.

Comment: @C2486 I thought you guess:
The form actions are `{{route('pages.postOnlineEnquiry')}}` and `{{route('pages.postGuestRegistration')}}` and remember the root cause is from the routing. tnx )

Comment: @NigelRen Okay that may not be possible. And now you see the problem clear before you. Could you post an answer considering **either changing the path or the method**? I don't think that works in this case. Should I consider another controller or leave the whole requirement behind?

Comment: Perhaps the answer posted by C2486 may do the job.

Answer (score 1):

@NigelRen is right you can't have multiple route with same url and same method `get`,`post`...

So My suggestion is, Use hidden input to differentiate both in your controller

```
<form action="{{route('guest_or_online')}}" method="post">
    .....
    .....
    <input type="hidden" value="guest"  name="type">
</form>

<form action="{{route('guest_or_online')}}" method="post">
    .....
    .....
    <input type="hidden" value="online" name="type">
</form>
```

So your route would be only one, which is

```
Route::post('/', ['uses' => 'PageController@GuestOrOnline', 'as' => 'guest_or_online']);
```

In your controller you can then call each function by getting value of `type`

```
public function GuestOrOnline(Request $request){
    if($request->type == "guest"){
        return $this->postGuestRegistration($request);
    }else{
        return $this->postOnlineEnquiry($request);
    }
}
```